# Mysql Log trigger

Tags: mysql, logging, triggers

I was wondering if there is a possibility to log changes from multiple Tables into one Log-Table. Every column should be logged into own row.

The Tables are not identical, but each has:

- UID (PK),
- CREATED (datetime),
- MODIFIED (datetime),
- MODIFIED_BY (id)

Some Tables have additional columns, for example:

- Data_Table_1 has additional columns: NAME, ACTIVE, ORDER
- Data_Table_2 has additional columns: DATABASE, ACTIVE, POSITION_NAME

And the Log_Table should have following columns:

- LOG_UID - (PK)
- EDITED - datetime filled by NOW
- TABLE- filled by table name that has been changed (Data_Table_1, Data_Table_2)
- COLUMN- filled by corresponding column, that was changed
- USER - filled by MODIFIED_BY
- VALUE - filled by value of each column in the query that has been changed
- TYPE- INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE
- LOG_GROUP_UID - which rows correspond to the same query
- LAST_LOG_GROUP_UID - (not really necessary) which was the last query that
- LAST_LOG_UID - (not really necessary) which is the previous corresponding row in this Table

I would like just one Log-Table which logs all initial values, updates and deletes for all Tables (which have or have not same columns), except itself. It should happen in mysql, so every change in phpMyAdmin, php, python... is logged and

Is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need to audit data changes instead of being able to see the state of the data on a given date, because it would be very complex to reconstruct the state of the data based on your solution (correct if I'm wrong in this assumption). I don't think the idea is viable, because even for very small databases your log table will be huge, and therefore very hard to properly manage.

A painless solution to audit data changes is to create a history table for each table you want to track. this table will have an entry for each insert, update and delete query executed on each row. the structure of the history table will be the same as the table it tracks except for three additional columns, a column to store the operation that occurred, a column to store a sequence number and a column to hold the occurrence timestamp.

The following query results in the SQL needed to create these audit tables, but it will only work if:

1. your tables do not start with `_` (because the audit tables will
   do);
2. your tables have a non composite primary key;
3. your tables don't have columns named Registrated, Action and
   Revision.

Query:

```
SET sql_mode = 'PIPES_AS_CONCAT';

SELECT
    'CREATE TABLE __' || table_name || ' LIKE ' || table_name || ';\r\n' ||
    'RENAME TABLE __' || table_name || ' TO _' || table_name || ';\r\n' ||
    'ALTER TABLE _' || table_name || ' ADD Registrated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL FIRST;\r\n' ||
    'ALTER TABLE _' || table_name || ' ADD Action TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL FIRST;\r\n' ||
    'ALTER TABLE _' || table_name || ' ADD Revision INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL FIRST;\r\n' ||
    'ALTER TABLE _' || table_name || ' MODIFY ' || column_name || ' ' || UPPER(data_type) || IF(is_nullable = 'NO', ' NOT NULL', '') || ';\r\n' ||
    'ALTER TABLE _' || table_name || ' DROP PRIMARY KEY;\r\n' ||
    'ALTER TABLE _' || table_name || ' MODIFY COLUMN Revision INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;\r\n' ||
    'CREATE TRIGGER i' || table_name || ' AFTER INSERT ON ' || table_name || ' FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO _' || table_name || ' SELECT NULL, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ' || table_name || '.* FROM ' || table_name || ' WHERE ' || table_name || '.' || column_name || ' = NEW.' || column_name || ';\r\n' ||
    'CREATE TRIGGER u' || table_name || ' AFTER UPDATE ON ' || table_name || ' FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO _' || table_name || ' SELECT NULL, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ' || table_name || '.* FROM ' || table_name || ' WHERE ' || table_name || '.' || column_name || ' = NEW.' || column_name || ';\r\n' ||
    'CREATE TRIGGER d' || table_name || ' BEFORE DELETE ON ' || table_name || ' FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO _' || table_name || ' SELECT NULL, 3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ' || table_name || '.* FROM ' || table_name || ' WHERE ' || table_name || '.' || column_name || ' = OLD.' || column_name || ';'
FROM information_schema.tables
JOIN information_schema.table_constraints USING (table_schema, table_name)
JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage USING (table_schema, table_name, constraint_name)
JOIN information_schema.columns USING (table_schema, table_name, column_name) 
WHERE
    information_schema.tables.table_schema = (SELECT DATABASE()) AND
    information_schema.table_constraints.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY';
```

Note 1: foreign Keys are a referential integrity tool, not a performance tool. A good database model will perform better, but foreign keys itself causes more processing to happen, not less. The `CREATE TABLE LIKE` will create an empty table based on the definition of the original table, including any column attributes and indexes, but everything else (like data, foreign keys, etc) is ignored. The data integrity is being validated by the original tables constraints, so there is no gain by having foreign keys in the audit tables.